# Rsync with Ansible times out or fails

Tags: ansible, rsync

I have 3 hosts, AnsibleMast, DataRepo, and Node, where Node is any number of targets for Ansible. I am trying to get Node to use rsync to get a file from DataRepo.

If I am on Node and execute this command the file is transferred as expected:

```
rsync -avzL deployer@datarepo:/home/deployer/data/sbc/cbdbexport /tmp/.
```

I created this task:

```
- name: Copy the database backup file to the target node
  command: 'rsync -azL deployer@datarepo:/home/deployer/data/sbc/cbdbexport /tmp/.'
```

When executed it just hangs. I can look on the target and verify that its running.

```
[deployer@steve ~]$ ps -ef | grep ssh
deployer  3778  3777  0 14:00 pts/2    00:00:00 ssh -l deployer datarepo rsync --server --sender -lLogDtprze.iLs . /home/deployer/data/sbc/cbdbexport
```

I created this task using the synchronize module:

```
- name: Copy the database backup file to the target node
  synchronize:
    rsync_path: /usr/bin/rsync
    mode: pull
    src: rsync://datarepo:/home/deployer/data/sbc/cbdbexport
    dest: /tmp/
    archive: no
    copy_links: yes
```

It eventually times out. It also never appears to be running when I execute ps -ef | grep ssh:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --copy-links --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L rsync://datarepo:/home/deployer/data/sbc/cbdbexport /tmp/", "failed": true, "msg": "rsync: failed to connect to datarepo: Connection timed out (110)\nrsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(124) [receiver=3.0.6]\n", "rc": 10}
```

After the Ansible tasks fail I test that I can ssh from Node to DataRepo with no issue. I test that I can run the raw rysnc command. Both work as expected.

Question:
1. Why are either of the Ansible tasks failing? Is there something obvious that I am missing to make it work like the raw command?

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is wrong, you are trying to use an actual rsync share (which would mean you are running rsync as a daemon on **datarepo**) but the actual command you exemplify as working is using rsync over ssh. So the below is not correct
`src: rsync://datarepo:/home/deployer/data/sbc/cbdbexport`
and I think it should be
`src: /home/deployer/data/sbc/cbdbexport`

You can also add `async` to the task if you expect it to run for a long time, to avoid network hiccups or ssh timeouts to affect the task, something like the below, which would cause it to wait for one hour (3600 seconds = one hour):

```
- name: Copy the database backup file to the target node
  synchronize:
    rsync_path: /usr/bin/rsync
    mode: pull
    src: /home/deployer/data/sbc/cbdbexport
    dest: /tmp/
    archive: no
    copy_links: yes
  async: 3600
```

Comment: Async is not valid for the command:
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "async is not supported for this task."}

Comment: Rsync in pull mode seems to want a module name. I have a workaround using scp. I will get back to this some time in the future. 

- name: Copy the database backup file to the target node
  command: 'scp <hostname>:{{database_path}} /pkgtmp/cbdbexport'
  async: 3600
  poll: 5